# Receive File from pdfcompare result

Tags: java

I'm using the [pdfcompare Library](https://github.com/red6/pdfcompare) and it works perfectly. What I'm struggling with is that I can't manage to put the result in a java.io.File data type.

Should I write the result to a file temporarily then read it into a java.io.File and finally delete it?

How would you proceed in such a situation?

Thanks for any suggestion!

This is the method where I try to return a java.io.File:

```
public File compare(CompareJob compareJob) {
        File leftFile = compareJob.getFile1();
        File rightFile = compareJob.getFile2();

        File returnFile = null;

        try {
            final CompareResult result = new PdfComparator(leftFile, rightFile).compare();

            if (result.isEqual()) {
                System.out.print("equal");
                returnFile = leftFile;
            } else {
                System.out.print("not equal");
                returnFile = (File) result;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnFile;
    }
```

I've created a separate project where I've tested the library if it does return a pdf and it does.

Comment: So what is doing fine and what is not? Paste code.

Answer (score 0):

Use NIO operation
Use File writer and then use move method . This might help you.

If possible please share code ,I can help you in better way.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I've added the method I'm talking about. I don't understand what you've meant with "file writer and then use move method".